# How to use a thread to send message every 0.3 seconds?

Tags: c++, multithreading

My code is like this,

```
int main() {
    while(true) {

    ...//calculate the result(about 0.25s)
    int result = ...;
    }
}
```

In my code, every loop i can get a new result value,i want to use thread to save the result value and output the latest value every 0.3s. How can i do that?Because i haven't used thread before.Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy (and really clunky) way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>

// 0.3 seconds
constexpr     std::chrono::duration<int, std::micro> ms300(300000);
// 0.1 seconds for time waster.
constexpr     std::chrono::duration<int, std::micro> ms100(100000);

// thread task loop 
void taskloop()
{
    // just 10 iterations. Replace with proper termination condition
    for (int count = 0; count < 10; count++) 
    {
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        //calculate result
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(ms100); // time waster for test

        // output result.
        std::cout << start.time_since_epoch().count() << ":" << count << std::endl;
        auto delta = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
        auto sleeptime =ms300 - delta;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(sleeptime);
    }
}
int main()
{
    // start thread and call taskloop
    std::thread testthread(taskloop);
    // wait for thread to end.
    testthread.join();
}
```

Comment: @kookoo121 how's that?

Comment: Thank you very much!But in my code, there is a loop in main Thread, do i need join()?

Comment: You don't need join if you can be certain main won't end before the thread's finished doing it's job.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>         // std::this_thread::sleep_for
#include <chrono>         // std::chrono::seconds

using namespace std;


int main() {

    while (true) {

        //calculate the result(about 0.25s)
        cout << "0.3 Seconds now!";
        this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3 / 10));

    }

}
```

This uses `thread` and `chrono`. You can find it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/this_thread/sleep_for/).

Comment: Thank you for your comment.But in this case, the main thread just wait for  more 0.3s.It can not output every 0.3s

Comment: @kookoo121 Ooppss.. I'm sorry. I guess I have a lot more to learn haha. Also thank you for being kind!